# Automapper ForAllPropertyMaps() predicate has unexpected side effects

Tags: automapper

I have some experimental code that uses the ForAllPropertyMaps() method in Automapper to register a resolver for certain properties, depending on a predicate (see demo code below).

In short, I am trying to detect source properties that are Nullable, and to skip mapping when the source property has HasValue == true. In practise this is achieved by supplying the destination property's value as the source value, rather than 'skipping' the mapping altogether.

This pattern works fine, but the behaviour changes to setting a value of default(T) instead of the not setting the property, when the ForAllPropertyMaps() predicate is modified in a way that doesn't change its result (currently I have set to return true in all examples).

Here is the full program that demonstrates the issue:

```
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.Internal;

namespace AutomapperTest;

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MapperConfiguration config = new(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<double?, double>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>();
            cfg.IgnoreSourceWhenNull();

        });
        config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        Source source = new()
        {
            Double = null
        };

        Dest? dest2 = mapper.Map<Dest>(source);

        if (dest2.Double != 42.0)
            Console.WriteLine($"Fail; destination value has been replaced. Value is [{dest2.Double}]");
    }
}

public class Source
{
    public double? Double { get; set; }
}

public class Dest
{
    public double Double { get; set; } = 42.0;
}

static class AutomapperExtensions
{
    public static void IgnoreSourceWhenNull(this IMapperConfigurationExpression cfg)
    {
        var internalCfg = cfg.Internal();

        internalCfg.ForAllPropertyMaps(pm =>
        {
            // Simply getting the SourceType property results in a different Automapper execution plan, and a
            // change in behavior (the test fails instead of succeeding).
            //var foo = pm.SourceType;

            // The test for Nullable<T> that we would like to do.
            //var isNullable = pm.SourceType.IsGenericType && (pm.SourceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>));

            return true;
        },
        (pm, c) =>
        {
            c.MapFrom<Resolver, object>(pm.SourceMember.Name);
        });
    }
}

class Resolver : IMemberValueResolver<object, object, object, object>
{
    public object Resolve(
        object source,
        object destination,
        object sourceMember,
        object destinationMember,
        ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return sourceMember ?? destinationMember;
    }
}
```

I am using a dotnet 6 console app, and Automapper 11.0.1.

The above code works as expected, but then fails if the following line is commented out:

```
//var foo = pm.SourceType;
```

Even though in principle that should have no effect.

Here are the two expression trees obtained using:

```
var plan = config.BuildExecutionPlan(typeof(Source),typeof(Dest));
```

And the ReadableExpressions.Visualizers Visual Studio extension.

Working expression tree:

```
(source, destination, context) =>
{
    AutomapNullable.Dest typeMapDestination;
    return (source == null)
        ? null
        : {
            typeMapDestination = destination ?? new AutomapNullable.Dest();
            try
            {
                object resolvedValue = ((AutoMapper.IMemberValueResolver<object, object, object, object>)context.CreateInstance(typeof(AutomapNullable.AutoMapperExtensions.Resolver))).Resolve(
                    (object)source,
                    (object)typeMapDestination,
                    source.Double,
                    typeMapDestination.Double,
                    context);
                double mappedValue = (resolvedValue == null)
                    ? default(double)
                    : context.MapInternal(
                        resolvedValue,
                        (destination == null) ? default(double) : typeMapDestination.Double,
                        AutoMapper.PropertyMap);
                typeMapDestination.Double = mappedValue;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                throw AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.MemberMappingError(ex, AutoMapper.PropertyMap);
            }

            return typeMapDestination;
        };
}
```

Failing expression tree:

```
(source, destination, context) =>
{
    AutomapNullable.Dest typeMapDestination;
    return (source == null)
        ? null
        : {
            typeMapDestination = destination ?? new AutomapNullable.Dest();
            try
            {
                object resolvedValue = ((AutoMapper.IMemberValueResolver<object, object, object, object>)context.CreateInstance(typeof(AutomapNullable.AutoMapperExtensions.Resolver))).Resolve(
                    (object)source,
                    (object)typeMapDestination,
                    source.Double,
                    typeMapDestination.Double,
                    context);
                double mappedValue = (resolvedValue == null)
                    ? default(double)
                    : {
                        double typeMapDestination;
                        return ((double?)resolvedValue).HasValue
                            ? {
                                typeMapDestination = default(double);

                                return typeMapDestination;
                            }
                            : default(double);
                    };

                typeMapDestination.Double = mappedValue;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                throw AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.MemberMappingError(ex, AutoMapper.PropertyMap);
            }

            return typeMapDestination;
        };
}
```

It looks to me that in the failing expression tree, the resolved value is not being used after being checked for HasValue == true.

Comment: Getters can have side effects when they are cached, and yes, `SourceType` is cached.

Comment: You can try a [custom object mapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/e39ecca35ea560f21364ce6abdc8a0e5e25470e0/src/UnitTests/Mappers/CustomMapperTests.cs#L123) for `Nullable<>` instead of `ForAllPropertyMaps`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu For the record, that approach is not viable here, because the mapper cannot conditionally set the destination property, and it does not have access to the destination property's current value to pass in when the source is null. Actually, it may be possible because there are 'source' and 'destination' parameters on the ITypeConverter.Convert() but the 'destination' is set to default(T) for the destination type. Which I think is a bug, and possibly the same bug that results in problem described by this SO question.

Comment: But maybe a type converter is a simpler way after all, but that only works when you pass a destination object, by design. Indeed, object mappers don't get to handle null, so it couldn't possibly work for null.